# tk, tcl exec stderr, stdout separately

Tags: scripting, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a tcl script.

The problem is that I have to call a script that can write something to stderr (it's not a critical failure).

I would like to capture stderr and stdout separately in tk/tcl.

```
if { [catch {exec "./script.sh" << $data } result] } {
   puts "$::errorInfo"
}
```

This code will return my result but it also contains stderr.

Also I would like to get the result to a variable.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Minor issue: include the closing square bracket in your code example. +1 for a great question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the command as a pipe instead of using `exec`, you can separate stdout and stderr.  See http://wiki.tcl.tk/close

```
set data {here is some data}
set command {sh -c {
    echo "to stdout"
    read line
    echo "$line"
    echo >&2 "to stderr"
    exit 42
}}
set pipe [open "| $command" w+]
puts $pipe $data
flush $pipe
set standard_output [read -nonewline $pipe]
set exit_status 0
if {[catch {close $pipe} standard_error] != 0} {
    global errorCode
    if {"CHILDSTATUS" == [lindex $errorCode 0]} {
        set exit_status [lindex $errorCode 2]
    }
}
puts "exit status is $exit_status"
puts "captured standard output: {$standard_output}"
puts "captured standard error: {$standard_error}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the 2> to redirect stderr:

```
if { [catch {exec "./script.sh" << $data 2> error.txt} result } {
   puts "$::errorInfo"
}
```

You can then read the contents of error.txt:

```
package require Tclx; # Needed for the read_file command
set err [read_file error.txt]
puts "s1: err = $err"
```

Comment: I was hoping to get it directly into a variable without temporary files. I knew it was possible this way but I really don't like temp files.